# QuickBooks SDK Installation Stops on Error Code 0x800F081F

Tags: quickbooks

I am trying to install the QuickBooks SDK v13 on a windows 10 computer for development and then again on a Windows 2016 Machine for production use.

I am getting stuck in a loop of trying to install old .Net Frameworks.

I am following these instructions:

https://developer.intuit.com/docs/01_quickbooks_desktop/1_get_started/20_download_and__install_the_sdk

Here are some of the screens I am seeing stepping thru the instructions:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I am posting this on Stackoverflow because this is an installation of an SDK problem.

Is there a way to run the installer with .NET Framework 4.x?

Am I using the wrong version of the installer?  It seems very strange that is requires such an old version of .NET Framework.

I can try to figure out why the old .NET Framework versions do not install but before I do that I want to determine if I am off track with something related QuickBooks.

At this time I am not going to try to install old versions of .NET.  I am going to confirm that the QB SDK actually needs those versions or find out if there are different SDKs that use current technology.

Comment: Have you looked at this page? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/install/dotnet-35-windows-10

Answer (score 0):

I just clicked "No" on the "Would you like to install it now?" question and it seemed to install fine.

However, I did get this AFTER the install of the sdk:

[image]

This leads to the next question: does Quickbooks SDK use .NET Framework 3.5 or does the installer use 3.5?